# Zend 1 on Ubuntu with MSSQL not working

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, sql-server, php5, zend-framework

Does anyone know how to solve the following issue? If not, does anyone know how to setup Zend 1 on Linux to communicate with msSQL server?

We get the following error in the nginx logs when trying to use freetds and the pdo_dblib adapter.  We're running Zend 1.2 on Ubuntu 12.04 using nginx 1.2.7

```
2013/02/27 20:48:24 [error] 9057#0: *28 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Warning:  include_once(Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Dblib.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /www/development/library/Zend/Loader.php on line 146
PHP message: PHP Warning:  include_once(): Failed opening 'Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Dblib.php' for inclusion (include_path='/www/development/application/../library:/www/development/library:.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /www/development/library/Zend/Loader.php on line 146
PHP message: PHP Warning:  include_once(Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Dblib.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /www/development/library/Zend/Loader.php on line 146
PHP message: PHP Warning:  include_once(): Failed opening 'Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Dblib.php' for inclusion (include_path='/www/development/application/../library:/www/development/library:.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /www/development/library/Zend/Loader.php on line 146
PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Zend_Exception' with message 'File "Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Dblib.php" does not exist or class "Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Dblib" was not found in the file' in /www/development/library/Zend/Loader.php:99
Stack trace:
0 /www/development/library/Zend/Db.php(263): Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Db_Adapter...')
1 /www/development/library/Zend/Application/Resource/Db.php(142): Zend_Db::factory('PDO_DBLIB', Array)
2 /www/development/library/Zend/Application/Resource/Db.php(154): Zend_Application_Resource_Db->getDbAdapter()
3 /www/development/library/Zend/Application/Bootstrap/BootstrapAbstract.php(680): Zend_Application_Resource_Db->init()
4 /www/development/library/Zend/Application/Bootstrap/BootstrapAbstract.php(623): Zend_Application_Bootstrap_BootstrapAbstract->_executeResource('db')
5 /www/development/library/Zend/Application/Bootstrap/BootstrapAbstract.php(583): Zend_Application_Bootstrap_BootstrapAbstract->_bootstrap(NULL)
6 /www/development/library/Zend/Appli" while reading response header from upstream, client: 108
```

We've tried [this](http://bharatikunal.wordpress.com/2008/06/19/connecting-mssql-server-with-zend-framework-on-linux/) and [this](http://blog.josephwilk.net/databases/pdo-zend-framework-playing-nicely-with-mssql.html) tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a StackOverflow question than ServerFault. 
Double check your adapter setting, it probably needs to be Pdo_Mssql.